# Uboot timer with interrupts

Tags: timer, u-boot

I would like to show Uboot progress with blinking LED's. For this purpose I need delay which will not use while loop (non-blocking), but interrupts instead.

Is there any implementation of timers inside Uboot ? 
I have looked a little bit, but I didn't find non-blocking delays. 
Do I need to implement if from scratch ?

I use at91SAM9 with Uboot 2010.06.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I use U-Boot for ARM processors, I have not seen any interrupt implementions. Polling gets the job done for all the peripheral devices I'm familiar with. Timer is implemented, I like the simplicity of their udelay_masked().

I haven't used it, but it looks like CONFIG_SHOW_BOOT_PROGRESS is available to you. README suggests you add show_boot_progress(int) to blink the LED. Each blink would use blocking delay. Maybe you use different color and/or blink pattern for the checkpoints you want to show have passed.